# 111 Wei Gas Fee ? what's happenin on my wallet ? 30K NFT inside

Tags: solidity, remix, etherscan, nft, wei

whenever am i deposit into my wallet my balance will all go firstly they take 111 wei but whole ecosystem based on 1 wei.

[image]
Wallet address/Network
0xD0190c377A7800d80E3cA6e112b62fD1744D17Ca
Unauthorized transaction link(s)
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x58dbc658c3f5f3f307dcc53330773d9c8629bba744e5a1fae4648b9f0059dfec
Missing amount (estimated in $USD)
Value:
111 wei

and after i was looked on my smartcontracts with remix.ethereum.ide inside there is 15 wallet inside. idk which or whois adresses of theese [image]

Answer (score 1):

Any unauthorized transaction means that either your mnemonic seed phrase or the private key is compromised and somebody has it.

Suggestion: Create a new wallet account and keep keys, passcodes, and seed phrases safe.